# Changing block background color in beamerposter

Tags: beamer, beamerposter

I'm using [beamerthemeRJH](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/beamer-poster/) theme for my poster presentation. The `.sty` file to this theme can be obtained from [here](http://robjhyndman.com/research/beamerthemeRJH.sty). I want to get `OliveGreen`  rather than blue color for block background. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.sty` file for the theme you mentioned is very well commented, and so it's easy to change colors of the elements.

To change the background color to `OliveGreen`, first add the option `dvipsnames` to the Beamer class, so that you can use this name for the color.

Next, go into the `.sty` file of `RJH` theme, locate the part whose color you'd like to change, say `% body colors and fonts`. You'll notice that the `\setbeamercolor` command has a `fg=<colorname>,bg=<colorname>` argument; these specify the colors for foreground and background. If you want to change the background color to `OliveGreen`, then simply issue

```
\colorlet{<colorname>}{OliveGreen}
```

in the preamble. This will redefine `<colorname>` to be the color you specify. In the case of `% body colors and fonts`,

```
\colorlet{i6colorscheme3}{OliveGreen}
```

will change the background color of the poster to `OliveGreen`.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[final,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{RJH}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a2,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1cm}

\colorlet{i6colorscheme3}{OliveGreen} % change body background color

\title{The demise of the spotted swamp frog}
\author{Rob J Hyndman}
\footer{More information at \texttt{robjhyndman.com}}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{} 

\begin{textblock}{19.5}(1,5)
\begin{block}{The spotted frog habitat}
Blah blah blah
\end{block}

\begin{block}{Some interesting specimens}
Stuff and nonsense
\end{block}
\end{textblock}

\begin{textblock}{19.3}(21.8,5)
\begin{block}{My latest paper about frogs}
Published in the \emph{Journal of Irreproducible Results}.
\end{block}

\end{textblock}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Kevin C for your nice answer. Actually I want to change the blue color of blocks to olivegreen. Would you suggest me where I have to make changes. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: under the `% block environment`, you'll see that the `block title`'s background color is `i6colorblockbg`. Then `\colorlet{i6colorblockbg}{OliveGreen}` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin C for your help. I got the desired color for block but still struggling with headline background and footnote line background color. Could you give me few hints. Thanks

Comment: @MYaseen208: Try `\colorlet{i6colorschemeHeadline}{OliveGreen}`